# What is the sequence of call when creating new view in android

Tags: android, oncreate, ondraw, method-call

I have a Game class

Where I do this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    int diff = getIntent().getIntExtra(KEY_DIFFICULTY, DIFFICULTY_EASY);
    puzzle = getPuzzle(diff);
    calculateUsedTiles();
    puzzleView = new PuzzleView(this);
    Log.d(TAG,"new Puxxle");
    setContentView(puzzleView);
    Log.d(TAG,"setContent");
    puzzleView.requestFocus();
}
```

I have my PuzzleView Class where I have

```
public PuzzleView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    Log.d(TAG, "puzzleview");
    this.game = (Game) context;
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    Log.d(TAG, "w and h" + w + " " + h);
    width = w / 9f;
    height = h / 9f;
    Log.d(TAG, "selY and x" + selX + " " + selY);
    getRect(selX, selY, selRect);
    Log.d(TAG, "selY and x" + selX + " " + selY);
    Log.d(TAG, "onSizeChanged: width " + width + ", height " + height);
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
}

private void getRect(int x, int y, Rect rect) {
    rect.set((int) (x * width), (int) (y * height),
            (int) (x * width + width), (int) (y * height + height));
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Log.d(TAG,"drawing");
    Paint background = new Paint();
    background.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_background));
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), background);
}
```

Now my understanding was that when, in the Game class, we do `setContentView` that is when all the onsizeChanged and onDraw will be called, but it is happening after the setContent has been called.

Here's the sequence of my logs

```
  D/Game    ( 4175): onCreate 
  D/PuzzleView( 4175): puzzleview
  D/Game    ( 4175): new Puxxle
  D/Game    ( 4175): setContent
  D/PuzzleView( 4175): w and h320 430
  D/PuzzleView( 4175): selY and x0 0
  D/PuzzleView( 4175): selY and x0 0
  D/PuzzleView( 4175): onSizeChanged: width 35.555557, height 47.77778
  D/PuzzleView( 4175): drawing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When an Activity receives focus, it will be requested to draw its layout. The Android framework will handle the procedure for drawing, but the Activity must provide the root node 
>   of its layout hierarchy.

`setContentView()` just sets the root node, but the drawing of view occurs at some other point after `onCreate()`.